# google endpoint client library methods cannot execute

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine

I have an entity class User.

I generated endpoints classes and client library successfully.

I made the email attribute as the Id.

When invoking the getUser() int the android project like this:

```
Userendpoint.Builder builder = new Userendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
Userendpoint service = builder.build();
com.mycompany.services.userendpoint.model.User user = new User();
user = service.getUser("*****@hotmail.com").execute();
```

I got this error:

```
07-14 12:19:00.380  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
07-14 12:19:00.380  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ Not Found
07-14 12:19:00.380  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
07-14 12:19:00.390  30153-30180/com.emcloud.app W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

---

Even I have one deployed version of the project on app engine. When Running my android project it cannot enter the   `execute()`  method. And it stops execution at this method.